# JAR - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mortbay/jetty/Handler

Tags: java, ant, jar, jetty

Here is my ant target:

```
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="build/jar" />
    <jar destfile="build/jar/mobileAppQueuing.jar" basedir="build/classes">
        <fileset dir="library" includes="*.jar" />
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="Main" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

Here is what I have when I launch the ant target in verbose mode:

```
> ...    [javac]    
> /Users/jeromeansia/git/mobileAppQueuing/MobileAppQueuing/src/model/Share.java
> 
> jar:
>     [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/jeromeansia/git/mobileAppQueuing/MobileAppQueuing/build/jar
>       [jar] Building jar: /Users/jeromeansia/git/mobileAppQueuing/MobileAppQueuing/build/jar/mobileAppQueuing.jar
>       [jar] adding directory META-INF/
>       [jar] adding entry META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
>       [jar] adding directory controller/
>       [jar] adding directory model/
>       [jar] adding entry APIHandler.class
>       [jar] adding entry Main.class
>       [jar] adding entry controller/CtrlShare.class
>       [jar] adding entry model/Share.class
>       [jar] adding entry commons-codec-1.9.jar
>       [jar] adding entry commons-logging-1.2.jar
>       [jar] adding entry fluent-hc-4.5.jar
>       [jar] adding entry gson-2.3.1.jar
>       [jar] adding entry hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
>       [jar] adding entry httpclient-4.5.jar
>       [jar] adding entry httpclient-cache-4.5.jar
>       [jar] adding entry httpclient-win-4.5.jar
>       [jar] adding entry httpcore-4.4.1.jar
>       [jar] adding entry httpmime-4.5.jar
>       [jar] adding entry jetty-6.1.26.jar
>       [jar] adding entry jetty-util-6.1.26.jar
>       [jar] adding entry jna-4.1.0.jar
>       [jar] adding entry jna-platform-4.1.0.jar
>       [jar] adding entry junit-4.12.jar
>       [jar] adding entry mockito-all-1.9.5.jar
>       [jar] adding entry scribe-1.3.2.jar
>       [jar] adding entry servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar
>       [jar] adding entry twitter4j-async-4.0.3.jar
>       [jar] adding entry twitter4j-core-4.0.3.jar
>       [jar] adding entry twitter4j-examples-4.0.3.jar
>       [jar] adding entry twitter4j-media-support-4.0.3.jar
>       [jar] adding entry twitter4j-stream-4.0.3.jar
>       [jar] No Implementation-Title set.No Implementation-Version set.No Implementation-Vendor set.
>       [jar] Location: /Users/jeromeansia/git/mobileAppQueuing/MobileAppQueuing/build.xml:23:
> 
> 
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 1 second
```

But when I launch the jar I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mortbay/jetty/Handler
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2856)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1668)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mortbay.jetty.Handler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
```

Comment: when generated as a runnable jar with Eclipse, I do not have this issue

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution for a runnable jar:

```
> <target name="jar" depends="compile">     <mkdir dir="build/jar" />
>     <jar destfile="build/jar/mobileAppQueuing.jar" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
>         <manifest>
>             <attribute name="Main-Class" value="Main" />
>             <attribute name="Class-Path" value="." />
>         </manifest>
>         <fileset dir="bin" />
>         <zipgroupfileset dir="library" includes="*.jar"/>
>     </jar> </target>
```